# Can I display a person's full name for SMS in Google Hangouts?

Tags: contacts, sms, google-hangouts

For the Google Hangouts app, it appears that SMS messages (as opposed to actual Hangouts messages, which I'm sure would behave differently) only display a person's first name under an SMS received from them.  This is normally fine, but is confusing when you're in a group text with, say, a fella named "Bob Jones" and another fella names "Bob Smith".

The Google Hangouts phone notifications are specific when you first receive the SMS, but when scrolling through the messages in app I will simply see all messages being received from "Bob", with no way to disambiguate. I could view message details and look at the "From" phone number and see which Bob in my contacts has that number, but we all know that's not going to happen.

An ideal option for me would be to have Google Hangouts display a person's full name under each SMS.  Unfortunately I looked through the app's own settings menu, but could find no such option.

Has anyone else solved this problem?

Things I've considered:

- I thought about concatenating both peoples' names (i.e. "BobJones" and "BobSmith") but when I use a voice command to call someone, my concern is that the voice command wouldn't quite work with such weird pronunciations, especially considering I'm not actually working with names as simple as Bob, Jones, and Smith.

Comment: Does this work --- https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/4a1z0i/i_discovered_a_method_for_displaying_contact/ ?

Comment: @gunner It appears that this fix would last for a day.  But considering the issues the people on that post were having, there's probably not an ideal fix.  I'll just have to deal with it.

Thanks, though!